# How in the context of the terms, links to category pages I create?

Tags: php, hyperlink, preg-replace

I am a articles
I want anywhere in the article that my words were classified, the word is automatically linked to the category
i do it by preg_replace like this

```
$text = preg_replace('(hello|word1|word2)', '<a href="'.$link1.'">word</a>', $text);
$text = preg_replace('(word3|hello word|word4)', '<a href="'.$link2.'">word</a>', $text);
```

but when the word "hello world" exist on paper, "hello" is the link to the "$link1" and "word" can not link

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Negative Lookahead `(?! )` feature to not match `hello` string followed by `world` string on the first regexp, like this example:

```
$text = preg_replace('(hello(?! world)|word1|word2)', '<a href="'.$link1.'">word</a>', $text);
$text = preg_replace('(word3|hello world|word4)', '<a href="'.$link2.'">word</a>', $text);
```

PS: note that there is a typo in your second regexp: `hello word` instead `hello world`

References:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html
http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php